# How to wait for a particular user action

Tags: android, service, android-intent

Is it possible for my app to establish a pendingIntent in my background service and wait for a user action (like modify calendar event) ? And as soon as user adds a calendar event, I want a service/activity to be started ? Can it be done?

Can someone please help me with some backbone code so I can proceed in the right direction ?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Do you have to listen to event from other applications or your own?

Comment: I have my app. I want to get information as soon as user makes/edits a calendar entry (In his default calendar app)

Comment: So in short, I need to listen from other application (Calendar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most Android devices, this is not supported. Starting with Android 4.0, it is at least conceivable to write this, by using a `ContentObserver` on `CalendarContract`, but it will be unreliable -- your `Service` that is the observer would need to try to run forever, and that does not work. And even this would only work for the AOSP Calendar application -- if the user is using another calendar app, `CalendarContract` may not be involved.